# How to scroll per page on OwlCarousel2 using navigation?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

On previous version, i can use `scrollPerPage: true` to slide entire page instead of per item. However, when i tried it on **OwlCarousel2**, it doesn't seem to work. How do i make scrollperpage work on OwlCarousel2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owl Carousel version 2 has two params, that can help you. You must set `slideBy` equal to param `items`. For ex.:

```
jQuery('#carousel').owlCarousel({
 ...
 slideBy: 5,
 items: 5,
 responsive:{
    0:{
        slideBy: 1,
        items: 1
    },
    600:{
        slideBy: 3,
        items: 3
    },
    1000:{
        slideBy: 5,
        items: 5
    }
}
});
```

And if responsive settings has other items number you must add `slideBy` also that must be equal to `items`

Comment: Thank you!! I found out about the "slideBy" option the other day but forgot to update my post with answer but thans for reminding me with the responsive settings, i was actually planning to use it on my other caoursel so it's a huge help! Thanks!